# Data Formatting with Javascript to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, webduino

I'm using javascript to upload data from webduino, but have trouble with the formatting part.
The part my js pushes data to Firebase is as follows:

```
 myFirebase.push({
             messages:{
              time:get_time("hms"),
              d
             }
            });
```

The results in Firebase look like this:
[image: Present Results]

However, to make the database manageable, it has to be like this:

[image: Prefered Results]

which the "messages" class is above all data.

Please let me know if there is anyway I can adjust my js code to achieve this, thank you!

Comment: The rest of the js controller codes are here: https://bin.webduino.io/pidof/3/edit?html,output

Comment: I'm confused. Is the object you're pushing in supposed to contain more than one message?

Comment: Nope, but they are all uder the message ... class? ref? Sorry im totally new to this. The messages (1 name + 1 text as a pair) comes in one by one , individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it,

```
myFirebase = new Firebase("https://watercup-e06b3.firebaseio.com/messages/");
```

just add the "/messages" and everything will work!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do but I'm unsure:

```
let messagesRef = myFirebase.ref('messages')
messagesRef.push({name: 'blah', text: 'bluh'})
```

Comment: It looks very reasonable but didn't work ... it freezes when trying to upload Thanks anyway!